# How to call native VC++6 library (with std::string as parameters) from C#

Tags: c#

I have a native dynamic link library written in VC++6 and I do not have access to the source code. I would like to convert it to managed code so that C# can call this library. The problem is that the VC6 library heavily makes use of std::vector and std::string as function parameters and there is no way of marshaling these types into C# directly.

So what I need is a bridge between VC6 and C# and I implemented a VC++2005 wrapper for VC++6.

However, I realized from the reply (by jalf) to the following thread that "VC++6 and VC++2005 have different definitions of std::string (and the compilers may also insert different padding and other changes), and the result is garbage, and/or unpredictable behavior and crashes".

[Passing std::string from VC++2005 to VC++6 DLL results in garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804359/passing-stdstring-from-vc2005-to-vc6-dll-results-in-garbage)

So now, the big question is, **how can I call the VC++6 native library from C#?**

I am at a loss and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got access to VC++6, compile the "bridging/wrapper" dll with that. Then, expose functions with types you can P/Invoke from C# such as Char* etc..

BTW,
You can probably get a "used" license on eBay or something for cheap.

**EDIT:**
Here's a sample code for what you've asked (I think...):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("somedll.dll")]
public static extern int Fun1(int n, IntPtr[] lpNames);


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
List<string> strList = new List<string>();

IntPtr[] strPointerArr = new IntPtr[strList.Count];
for(int i=0; i<strList.Count; ++i){
    strPointerArr[i] = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(strList[i]);
}
Fun1(strList.Count, strPointerArr);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution at first but how do you convert this complex type std::vector<std::string> to something else that can be P/Invoke from C#?

Comment: If you just need to pass it, `const char**` (i.e. dynamic array of dynamic arrays of chars) would do the trick (use `CoTaskMemAlloc`, and require the caller to free it).

Comment: What about the other way round where the "bridging/wrapper" dll written in VC++6 wants to pass char** back to C#? In this case, the memory can't be deallocated because C# cannot do this.

Comment: You can use the memory allocation functions from Kernerl32.dll: GlobalAlloc, GlobalFree and P\Invoke them

Comment: Or even use: Marshal.FreeHGlobal Method. Looking at MSDN, I think it's the same

Comment: I haven't done any memory allocation before in C# so I am kind of new to this. Can someone please provide examples of how memory for the following C# type (List<String>) can be allocated for passing to the bridging dll which expects const char** as an argument. And also the code for how to actually pass this?